# Why iife not working in a simple example?

Tags: javascript, iife

I can't understand why functional expression call doesn't work and throws an error.

Can you explain it to me?

```js
var a = function (x) {
  alert(x)
}

(function() {
   a(1);
}());
```

Thanks to everyone

The task was much easier than I thought

Comment: ^ Order of parentheses is important.

Comment: This doesn't make sense anymore, the malfunctionning code got edited into a working example by adding the semicolon...

Comment: @NinoFiliu  Indeed, I've put the error back in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh so it is. Go figure that the one time auto-semicolon insertion fails, I don't notice XD

Comment: A very rough rule of thumb is: If you're going to rely on ASI, anything starting with a `(` or `[` that isn't meant to be part of the previous expression should have a `;` in front of them, to avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: "it throws an error" -- what error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because JS is parsing the IIFE as an argument call for the function, do it like this with an added semi-colon

```js
var a = function (x) {
  alert(x)
};    
(function() {
   a(1);
}());
```

Comment: One of those times a semi-colon is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Because at the moment, where you call the function, the assignment has not happened yet.

```
var a; // hoisted, value undefined, no function

// later

a = function (x) {
    alert(x);
}(function() {
    a(1);      // a is still no function
}());
```

Or you need to insert a semicolon to separate the assignment from the call,

```js
var a = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
};
(function() {
  a(1);
}());
```

or take `void` for separation

```js
var a = function(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
void (function() {
  a(1);
}());
```

Comment: I'd edit to say clearly that the first function is being *called* and passed the second.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function a inside the IIFE Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
(function() {
  function a(x) {
    alert(x)
  }
  a('x')
}());
```

Comment: It doesn't matter where you define a. IIFE will run first. For it a will never exist until defined inside it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: @AshayMandwarya - No, that's just completely incorrect. IIFEs are run in the step-by-step execution of the code. That's approximately half the point of them. The problem in the OP's code is the lack of a semicolon. Simply adding it fixes the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ozmr38hj/