# TypeError: [] is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot command handler, and I keep getting this error:

```
(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*js`)).map(async (file) => {
    ^

TypeError: [] is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```js
const { Perms } = require('../Validation/Permissions');
const { Client } = require('discord.js')
const { promisify } = require("util")
const { glob } = require('glob');
const PG = promisify(glob)
const Ascii = require('ascii-table')

/** 
 * @param {Client} client
*/

module.exports = async (client) => {
    const Table = new Ascii('Command Loaded')

    CommandsArray = []

    (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const command = require(file);

        if (!command.name)
        return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], 'FAILED', 'Missing a name.')

        if (!command.description)
        return Table.addRow(command.name, 'FAILED', 'Missing the description.')

        if (command.permission) {
            if (Perms.includes(command.permission))
            command.defaultPermission = false;
            else
            return Table.addRow(command.name,'FAILED','Permission is invalid')
        }

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        CommandsArray.push(command);

        await Table.addRow(command.name, 'SUCCESSFUL');
    })

    console.log(Table.toString())

    // Permissions check //

    client.on('ready', async() => {
        const MainGuild = await client.guilds.cache.get('940180806696058910');

        MainGuild.commands.set(CommandsArray).then(async (command) => {
            const Roles = (commandName) => {
                const cmdPerms = CommandsArray.find((c) => c.name === commandName).permission
                if (!cmdPerms) return null;

                return MainGuild.roles.cache.filter((r) => r.permissions.has(cmdPerms))
            }

            const fullPermissions = command.reduce((accumulator, r) => {
                const roles = Roles(r.name);
                if (!roles) return accumulator;

                const permissions = roles.reduce((a, r) => {
                    return [...a,{id: r.id, type: 'ROLE', permission: true}]
                }, [])

                return [...accumulator, {id: r.id, permissions}]
            }, [])

            await MainGuild.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions });

        })

    })
}
```

I've done some googling, but I was unable to find anything related to just [], type error usually appears when there is a spelling mistake in your code. I have gone through my code numerous times and have been completely unable to find any mistakes, I just cannot figure this out.
I would really appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: [Why do I have to put a semicolon before a self executing anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46529352) | [Why iife not working in a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54650106) | [IIFE. TypeError: require(...)(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53186265) | [Semicolon before self-invoking function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7365172)

Answer (score 2):

Please use semi-colons!

Add ; onto the line above the PG where you define an empty array, JS sees the array and also brackets right after and this thinks you are executing a function because JS when compiled does not look at lines or spacing.

```js
CommandsArray = [];

(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*js`)).map(async (file) => {
```

Comment: "JS when compiled does not look at lines or spacing." - there are a couple of things wrong here. JS is not compiled, it is interpreted, and JavaScript does take new lines in to 
account for Automatic Semicolon Insertion.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.